# Angle of rotated line segment

Tags: geometry

I have the following set-up:

[image]

I know the radius, I know alpha, and I know X, what I'm trying to find is theta. Is there a formula for this (sorry if this is simple, having trouble searching for it).

Comment: What have you tried? BTW, in your image the whole pie wedge shaped piece can be rotated at will around its point (changing $\theta$), so the problem is underspecified.

Comment: @vonbrand - updated picture

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the triangle formed by the two radii and the segment connecting their ends is isoceles. Drawing a line down the center of it, we get two right triangles, each of which have  hypotenuse of length $r$ and one leg of length $\frac{X}{2}$. Thus, the angle of one of these right triangles that is opposite to the side formed from the $X$ segment is equal to
$$\arcsin\left(\frac{X/2}{r}\right),$$
and the difference $\theta-\alpha$ is formed by precisely two of these angles (one from each right triangle), so
$$\theta=\alpha+2\arcsin\left(\frac{X}{2r}\right).$$

Comment: @CoDEFRo:   In the limit that $X$ is small compared to $r$, we have $\arcsin \left(\frac X{2r}\right) \approx \frac X{2r}$ and this becomes $\theta=\alpha + \frac Xr$ (in radians).  This equates to replacing the straight segment $X$ with an arc of the circle.

Comment: Thanks Zev. @RossMillikan - Well actually I should've mentioned, I am rotating this line segment, so the distance would be the path traveled around the arc of the circle, ie an arc that is x amount long. Does that change anything?

Comment: @CoDEFRo:  If you measure $X$ around the circle, then the equation I gave is exact and you don't need the $\arcsin$.  Zev and I assumed that $X$ was measured as the distance between the endpoints in a straight line.

Comment: @CoDEFRo: In that case, just convert the length $X$ to radians,
$$\text{arc of length $X$ on circle of radius $r$}\quad \rightsquigarrow\quad \frac{X}{r}\text{ radians}$$
and add it to $\alpha$ (which must of course also be measured in radians) to produce $\theta$.

Comment: Just so you know I did update the picture in the problem.

Comment: @RossMillikan , Zev - Thanks guys,  really appreciate it.

Comment: @RossMillikan - Actually just wanted to verify, the theta = alpha + X/R is what I'd use now correct?

Comment: @CoDEFRo:  That is right